# How to schedule ServletContextListener to execute on a specified date and time

Tags: java, servlets, servletcontextlistener

I have a ServletContextListener which is executing on every 5 seconds.Now as per my need i have to set it to execute on 10th date of every month at 10 am.But i am not able to set it..

Here is my code..

```
@WebListener()
public class MyContext implements ServletContextListener {

private ScheduledExecutorService sched;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    sched = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    sched.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    sched.shutdownNow();
}
}
```

new MyTask() is the class that is called to excute.

Here is my timer code to run on particular schedule..

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.set(
            Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
            Calendar.TUESDAY);
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 51);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


    timer.schedule(
            new ReportGenerator(),
            date.getTime(),
            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
```

Please help me ..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: The `ServletContextListener` is not executing every 5 seconds. The servlet container invokes its `contextInitialized` method only once in the lifecycle of the application.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, After initialize, it will run ScheduledExecutorService on every 5 seconds.

Comment: @Masud The `ExecutorService` is working, not the `ServletContextListener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `@Schedule` of Timer Service of `EJB` or `Quartz`.

```
@Schedule(....)
```

For details, read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

Comment: Sir i updated my post with timer service code but i dont know how to use it in present context

Comment: @Adi, date.getTime() will return long value of currentTimeMillis and delay date.getTime() seconds. It will not run on the time of  date.getTime().

Comment: For your purpose, you need EJB or Quartz.

Comment: Sir i tested and its working fine only thing that i need is setting date as time is already set my concern is how to set date in Calendar.